# Coproducts in shapeless does not compile

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shapeless, coproduct

I'm experimenting with `shapeless` and now trying to understand `Generic` for Coproducts. Here is what I tried:

```
object ShapelessExperiments {
    final case class Test1()
    final case class Test2()
    final case class Test3()

    type Test = Test1 :+: Test2 :+: Test3 :+: CNil

    val t1: Test = Inr(Inl(Test2()))  //fine
    val t2: Test = Generic[Test].to(Test2())  //compile error
}
```

I expected `val t2` to be exactly the same as `val t1`, but unfortunately it does not even compile:

```
Error:(13, 25) could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic[com.test.ShapelessExperiments.Test]
  val t2: Test = Generic[Test].to(Test2())

Error:(13, 25) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit gen: shapeless.Generic[com.test.ShapelessExperiments.Test])shapeless.Generic.Aux[com.test.ShapelessExperiments.Test,gen.Repr] in object Generic.
Unspecified value parameter gen.
  val t2: Test = Generic[Test].to(Test2())
```

This error does is not really clear and helpful to me. Can you please explain what went wrong in the final case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Inject`:

```scala
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.coproduct.Inject // for converter object
import shapeless.syntax.inject._ // for nice syntax

object ShapelessExperiments extends App {
    final case class Test1()
    final case class Test2()
    final case class Test3()

    type Test = Test1 :+: Test2 :+: Test3 :+: CNil

    val t1: Test = Inr(Inl(Test2()))  //fine
    val t2: Test = Inject[Test, Test2].apply(Test2())
    val t3: Test = Test2().inject[Test]
    println(t1 == t2) // true
    println(t1 == t3) // true 
}
```

---

`Generic[A]` purpose is different: it says that `A` is isomorphic (can be transformed to and from, without any data loss) to some type `B`, where `B` is usually an `HList` (if `A` is a case class) or a `Coproduct` (if `A` is a sealed trait).

These instances are not available when `A` is an `HList` or a `Coproduct` itself [(source)](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/f9c90ec20b8062df1180bf55d8f5a4c8ec010c5e/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic.scala#L985).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But there is one thing that is unclear to me. Let's declare a `sealed trait TestBase` and make all `Test1`, `Test2` and `Test3` extend it. In this case we have `Generic[TestBase].to(Test2()) == Inr(Inl(Test2()))`. So `Generic[A]` makes sense only in cases if `A` is an `ADT` or a product of types... ?

Comment: @SomeName yes. `Generic` purpose is to convert between arbitrary ADT and shapeless types.